# Jquery Data Table not displaying the original table when search criteria is removed

Tags: jquery

I have a data table like attached one there are 2 check  boxes on screen, selecting one should show all rows with 'Category Code' COM, other should show all rows with category code 'PRS'.

My Jquery is below :

```
function filterme() {

var test="";
  //build a regex filter string with an or(|) condition
  var types = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedRoles"]:checked').map(function() {
    return '^' + this.value + '\$';
  }).get().join('|');

  otable = $('#dt').dataTable();
  otable.fnFilter(types, 2, true, false, false, false);
}
```

This works fine for the checkboxes but when none of the checkboxes are selected , it still shows up the last checkbox selected result.

Comment: When no checkboxes are selected, then your types variable will be an empty string. So the filtering may have no effect and that could be why the last result is still showing.  Maybe you need to find out how to reset the filtering for data tables?

Comment: Thanks Anthony, any suggestion to fix this up would be of great help. Should I treat unchecked ones as 'select All' ?

Comment: Maybe an if statement for if none are checked then show all data table rows, else your code that you have there

Comment: you need to declare `var test="";` outside of `filterme()` and pass it to it like `filterme(test){var self = test}`